# Return String from a Future function

Tags: flutter, dart

How can i return a string from a future function?

```
Future<String> functionA() async {
   var x = await fetchX();
   return x;
}   

Future<String> fetchX() {
   return Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 4), () => 'example');
}

Future<String> la() async {

  print(await functionA()); //this works correctly
  return await functionA(); //this return always an instance of Future
}
```

How can i return "example" from the future function, there is a method to do it, and where is my error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Future<String> fetch() async {
  return
    http.get('url')
    .then((response) => response.body);
 }
```

That way you can sneak a .catchError into there. :)

Comment: But for example with the shared preferences how could i return a string from this function?   `Future<String> conteggio() async {
    final dati = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    final numero = dati.getString('conteggio') ?? 0;
    return numero;
  }` I saved a string in "conteggio" but returns always the same error because the future function

Comment: You'll need to await the value returned from this function before you can use it as an actual String.   Do this codelab: https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await

Comment: I did the codelab, but it explained me how to print the value of a future function in the console, so i modified my code, but i don't understand how to return it... if you want help me thx!!

Comment: Oh ok i can use FutureBuilder to do it

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify what your function will return. All you have to do is add Future  to the beginning of the method.

```
Future<String> fetch() async {
    final response = await http.get('url');
    String conteggio = response.body;
    return conteggio;
 }
```

And you have to do this in a method. You can only assign constant values in fields other than methods.